# How to get exact touch location of object to add new child object at the same place

Tags: unity-game-engine, gameobject, touch-location

I have a base plane and when I click on the plane I need to add some other object at the exact location the user is touched. the newly added object is not a child of base plane it will be a child of another object which will present the same base plane

I tried using raycast position but it didn't work well.

```
Vector3 objLocation = new Vector3(raycastHit.transform.position.x, 180.0f, raycastHit.transform.position.z);
GameObject newObj = Instantiate(singleDustBin, objLocation, Quaternion.identity);                  newObj.transform.SetParent(dustBinPrefab.transform);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of `raycastHit.transform.position` use [`raycastHit.point`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RaycastHit-point.html) - that should do the trick

Comment: Sorry I am new to stack overflow usage so I don't know how to use it exactly , but I think I did what you ask.Thanks for your help.